# Any integer I input isn't recognized as an integer, without exception

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using Python 3.10.2, and it won't recognize any integers that I input as an integer. Be it 0, 1, 2.54, -96, or literally any other number, it's just not an integer, apparently.

I'm making a simple guessing game, and my code is as follows:

```
userGuess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 20: "))

if userGuess != int:
    print("Unrecognized input! Did you input a number?")
```

Regardless of the input, it always prints the "unrecognized input" message with the message it's supposed to print for that input ("Your guess was incorrect!", etc.)

If I use the `type()` function, it says that userGuess' type is -1. This also only happens when the user inputs the number, *not* if the number is pre-determined.

Comment: `int()` always returns an integer, you don't need to test it. If the user enters something that can't be converted to an integer, it will raise an exception.

Comment: `userGuess != int` is always true anyway, because an instance of an integer is never going to be equal to the class

Comment: You are looking for `isinstance(userGuess, int)`, but as @Barmar said, `int()` guarantees an integer

Comment: [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, [mark an answer correct by clicking on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627). You can also [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it if none of the ones you received solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the input is not a number, you should validate the input before transforming it into an `int`. You can check if a string contains only digits by using [`.isnumeric`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric). Something like:

```
userGuess = input("Guess a number between 1 and 20: ")

if not userGuess.isnumeric():
    # Input string is not a number
    print("Unrecognized input! Did you input a number?")
else:
    # Input is a number, is safe to transform into an int
    userGuess = int(userGuess)
```

This will only be useful if you're considering `int`s. If you want to allow `float`s (ex: 3.14), maybe you better try to transform the value into a `float` and see if it fails:

```
userGuess = input("Guess a number between 1 and 20: ")
try:
    userGuess = float(userGuess)
except ValueError:
    # Input string is not a float
    print("Unrecognized input! Did you input a number?")
```

Answer (score 0):

This check:

```
if userGuess != int:
```

will always be true because `userGuess` will never be the same as *the `int` type itself*.  What you're trying to do is check if `userGuess` is *an instance of an* `int`:

```
if isinstance(userGuess, int):
```

That, however, is not useful here, because this line:

```
userGuess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 20: "))
```

will either assign an `int` to `userGuess`, or raise an exception (which will immediately end execution of your script if nothing catches it).

If you want to catch the exception and provide an error, use `try/except`:

```
try:
    userGuess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 20: "))
except ValueError:
    print("Unrecognized input! Did you input a number?")
```

Note that if your script continues after this point, `userGuess` may not have any value assigned to it at all, so you should either end the script immediately since it's impossible to continue (this will probably happen anyway via another exception being raised as soon as you try to use `userGuess`), or use a `while` loop to re-try the input until `userGuess` does have a value.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I responded to fast.  Here is an updated response.  Trying to convert an non-numeric to int will result in a ValueError.  However, you can "catch" the error and respond according as follows.

```
userGuess = input("Guess a number between 1 and 20: ")


try:
    userGuess = int(userGuess)
except ValueError:
    print("Unrecognized input! Did you input a number?")
```

Comment: This will always return the same since there's an explicit conversion when defininf the `userGuess` variable. It does not change the current behaviour.

Comment: Yep, shame on me.  I answered too quickly and only responded to the invalid comparison.  See my updated response.